# Path of automatic script execution at startup

Tags: boot, powershell

My McAfee system complains execution of the following command at startup:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass ./TeamsFirewall.ps1
```

It invokes a powershell script I am not able to find on disk. Any hints on where I can view it? I can't guess what's command invocation path at this point

Comment: It appears McAfee is complaining about Teams. Try whitelisting Teams temporarily and see if that is the issue.

Comment: You can use e.g. Everything to make sure that file doesn't exist.

Comment: I'd look in **Event Viewer | Applications and Services Logs | Windows PowerShell** and then go through there and try to find an entry around the date and time your AV complained it blocked it, and see if there is more explicit detail in there to help identify the full path or some command before which may build the path. Additionally, see if there is a McAfee Event Viewer log somewhere in there too, it may give more verbose detail there. Happy hunting!!

Comment: I would look through the contents of your $profile file as well.  keep in mind that there are variant profile startup files for all users, and all hosts or something like that.  The use of ./ strongly suggests that the current location has been set to something by some earlier command in the startup file.

Comment: Did you really search your whole disk? If not I'd run this as admin `gci C:\ TeamsFirewall.ps1 -r -ea 0` to try and find it. Takes some time but will search your whole C:\ drive for it. Also, if this is a domain joined computer from work, ask your Sysadmin about it. Might be some logon script